# python pptx - check if object is a table, textbox or image

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-pptx

I use python 2.7 with python pptx,

I need to build a general function to center objects in my slide.

I know how to center any individual object type (textbox, table, image etc.) and need to build a function to tell which type of object is a given object and allign it properley.

I need something similar to:

```
if foo is bar
```

condition.

I found the table general object here [enter link description here](http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html)
and used the following code:

```
    if table is pptx.shapes.graphfrm.GraphicFrame.table:
        print "what"
```

It does not work,

How can i check if an object is some type of pptx object

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only actual objects that can appear on a slide are shapes. Visually, there might be items that "show through" from the slide master or layout, like a logo for instance, but from an object standpoint, a slide contains shapes and that's it.

So all the objects "on" a slide are in `slide.shapes`, and you can identify the type of each one using `Shape.shape_type`. This will be one of the values in the [MSO_SHAPE_TYPE enumeration](http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/enum/MsoShapeType.html), of which `TABLE` is one.

This code will enumerate the shape types on a given slide:

```
for shape in slide.shapes:
    print(shape.shape_type)
```

Comment: so if i want to check if an object is a picture i need to use : if pic.shape_type == 13 ?    where can i find a list of object types numbering?

Comment: btw, this works with text box and image, but not with table with that error AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'shape_type', how can i do that with a table?

Comment: @captainshai Interestingly, a table is not a shape. Rather, it is a graphical object (like a chart or smart art) contained in a GraphicsFrame shape. So you need to ask the container shape what type it is rather than the table itself.